# Etymology of とにかく

Tags: etymology

I was wondering with anyone knew the etymology of とにかく or any of its variants. The literal meaning doesn't make sense when you consider its actual meaning, so I got curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes from Classical Japanese idiomatic phrase とにかくに, analyzed into と ("some way") + に ("in") + かく ("that way; such a way") + に ("in"), and as a whole meant for "by some means or other" or "by any means".

The kanji you may often see ([兎に角](http://gogen-allguide.com/to/tonikaku.html)) is ateji.

Comment: Is ともかく similarly from a ともかくも? Also, did と leave any traces in the modern language? If it means the same as modern こう, it appears unrelated to any modern こそあど forms beginning in k-.

Comment: (1) Yes, ともかく comes from ともかくも, too. Other living idioms include とにもかくにも, ともあれ, とやかく etc. (2) と is almost always paired with かく (こう). 日本国語大辞典 suggests that "助詞「と」と同源か" (though no description about which と). It further says "「かく」や「さ」が話し手の積極的な指示姿勢を示すのに対して、これは非常に消極的な指示姿勢を示す。その消極性は、「いず（れ）」「ど（れ）」の不定未定指示とも異なり、一種の定指示でありながら、話し手の姿勢が定まらないところに成立する。", so I doubt it was a part of standard demonstrative paradigm.